# How to display subcategories product's min and max price on parent categories in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to display min and max price of subcategories product on parent categories pages.

```
function woocommerce_template_loop_subcategory_info( $category ) {
   $term = get_queried_object();

global $wpdb;

 # Get ALL related products prices related to a specific product category
 $results = $wpdb->get_col( "
 SELECT pm.meta_value
 FROM {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships as tr
 INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy as tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms as t ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_id
INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON tr.object_id = pm.post_id
WHERE tt.taxonomy LIKE 'product_cat'
AND t.term_id = {$term->term_id}
AND pm.meta_key = '_price'
");

// Sorting prices numerically
sort($results, SORT_NUMERIC);

// Get the min and max prices
$min = current($results);
$max = end($results);

// Format the price range after the title
$price_range = sprintf( __( ' <small>(from %1$s to %2$s)</small>', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $min ), wc_price( $max ) );
return $term_title . $price_range;
}
```

this is how to get the related product min and max price but i want to get subcategories price.